# How do I invoke protractor from within an express node server?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I have a browser app, served by an express node server. The server has a `/runprotractor` endpoint that runs protractor by ...

```
var launcher = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/launcher.js');
launcher.init(pathToConfigFile)
```

This works, but when the protractor suite completes, the node process terminates. I stubbed out `process.exit()` and sure enough, protractor was calling it. With process.exit stubbed out, the node server keeps running, but now subsequent protractor invocations silently do nothing. I'm guessing because there is some global state not being reset.

Any suggestions on how best to invoke protractor from an express server in a way that I can pass parameters that are accessible in my test specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I settled for a spawning a child process...

```
var pro = require('child_process').spawn('protractor', paramsForProtractorSpawn);
  pro.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });
```

Comment: hi, can you share how you require protractor and what paramsForProtractorSpawn contains?